# Is there a way to modify the scene in the Blueprint editor without affecting the blueprint itself?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I'm working on a game in Unreal Engine 4 where I have a similar set of blueprints. Each blueprint exists in a scene with trees and a night sky, so I want to be able to have such a scene load by default in the Blueprint editor viewport when I'm working on the blueprint; however, I do not want the scene to be exported/saved with the blueprint subject.

Is there a way to change the default blueprint editor scene in Unreal for specific sets of Blueprints?